# Error processing package while installing pycharm

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install pycharm on ubuntu 14.04 using terminal

```
sudo apt-get install pycharm
```

but i get the error bellow :

```
  dpkg: error processing package libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64:
     libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui2.4 (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
      Package libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libchromaprint0:amd64:
     libchromaprint0:amd64 depends on libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) | libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.10); however:
      Package libavcodec54 is not installed.
      Package libavcodec-extra-54:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libchromaprint0:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64:
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libchromaprint0 (>= 0.2); however:
      Package libchromaprint0:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libopencv-contrib2.4; however:
      Package libopencv-contrib2.4:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui2.4; however:
      Package libopencv-highgui2.4:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libopencv-legacy2.4; however:
      Package libopencv-legacy2.4:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libopencv-objdetect2.4; however:
      Package libopencv-objdetect2.4:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 depends on libopenjpeg2; however:
      Package libopenjpeg2:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64:
     gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 depends on libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) | libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13); however:
      Package libavcodec54 is not installed.
      Package libavcodec-extra-54:amd64 is not configured yet.
     gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 depends on libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1); however:
      Package libavformat54:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdlna0:
     libdlna0 depends on libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1); however:
      Package libavformat54:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libdlna0 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ushare:
     ushare depends on libdlna0; however:
      Package libdlna0 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package ushare (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libavcodec-extra:
     libavcodec-extra depends on libavcodec-extra-54; however:
      Package libavcodec-extra-54:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libavcodec-extra (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```